# Get String After Last Delimiter (BASIC)

Tags: basic, multivalue, pick

I am using BASIC programming language for work. I have an example string here:

> Eric*01*73839

By using the field function, I can grab either Eric or 01 like so:

```
ERIC = FIELD(STRING,"*",1)
01 = FIELD(STRING,"*",2)
```

However, if I wanted to grab the '73839' portion, how would this be done? I found it hard to find resources on google since it is so OLD.

**No,
`FIELD(STRING,"*",3)` doesn't work.

Comment: That doesn't look like any version of BASIC that I've ever seen, but my guess would be: `73839 = FIELD(STRING, 01 + "*", 1)` assuming the previous line is performed.  Also assuming you're allowed to name a variable as a number (01).

Comment: On second thought, the correct code based on the pattern you've demonstrated might be: `73839 = FIELD(STRING + "*", "*", 3)` (adding a third asterisk and then telling FIELD to find the third one which is now appended to STRING)

Answer (score 2):

You could always do some variation of converting the plain string to a dynamic string and extracting the third field.  For example:

```
CONVERT "*" TO @FM IN STRING
FIELD3 = STRING<3>
```

The specifics will depend on which flavor of multi-value BASIC you're using.  It might have to be more like:

```
EQU FM TO CHAR(253)    ;* Likely somewhere near the top, it will be used a lot
...
STRING = CHANGE(STRING,"*",FM)
FIELD3 = STRING<3>
```

If it needs to be more dynamic (there may be more than three fields and you always need the last one), you'll need to use DCOUNT (or COUNT+1) to find the last field.

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't right with either your code or your data (could that second * possibly be a unicode lookalike [https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/star-symbols/asterisk]?).  Or is STRING perhaps a reserved word in your flavor of PICK Basic?

```
STRING='Eric*01*73839'
CRT '1=':FIELD(STRING,'*',1)
CRT '2=':FIELD(STRING,'*',2)
CRT '3=':FIELD(STRING,'*',3)
```

Results in this for me:

```
1=Eric
2=01
3=73839
```